# What's an intuitive way to compute summation of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

What's an intuitive way to compute 
$$\log(1)+\log (2)+\log (3)+\cdots+\log (n-1)+\log (n)$$
or

for $n>a$
$$\log(a)+\log (a+1)+\log (a+2)+\cdots+\log (n-1)+\log (n) $$

I know the answer for general case is $$\log \left(\frac{n!}{(a-1)!}\right)$$

Comment: How did you find this answer?

Comment: You are missing $\log$.

Comment: now its correct :P

Comment: **Hint:** $\text{Sum}=\log\left(e^{\text{Sum}}\right)$. **Edit:** This is not an attempt on an intuitive way on how to see this.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$ \log(1)+\log (2)+\log (3)+....\log (n-1)+\log (n)=\log (n!) $$

and

$$ \log(a)+\log (a +1)+\log (a + 2)+....\log (n-1)+\log (n)= \log \prod_{i=a}^{n}i $$

**Note:** You need the property

> $$ \log(ab) = \log(a)+\log(b). $$